# Using Sinatra on Ubuntu 11.10 (Server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I have been learning Ruby (Rails/Sinatra) and it's good very good but OMFG how difficult is it to get running on a production server? Basically I want to have one of my domains running a RoR app. I have gone though countless tutorials on how to install ruby and get it running. I have managed to install Passenger (not sure how this even works) on apache2.

I have php installed maybe this is the problem. In order to get a sintra app working i have to do

```
ruby my_app_name.rb
```

this then works on www.mydomain.com:4567 how do i just get it running on www.mydomain.com? I'm obviously not the best when it comes to server configuration im still learning, i'm use to making a php app -> uploading and running haha not so easy with ruby =[

Hope someone can help point me in the right direction, thanks!!

Comment: It can be easy. For PHP, did you install PHP and apache yourself, or just choose a PHP-aware webhost? Because you have the same options with Ruby (e.g. Heroku, EngineYard, CloudFoundry, etc.)

Comment: Hi Mark, I installed PHP and Apache myself (well through linode tutorials) I have a VPS

Comment: it seems he wants to host it himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a port redirect. No need for passenger or anything. Just run it on 4567 and remap it to 80 and you're fine. Of course only if you don't expect a lot of traffic. But if that's the case you should be good to go. Also turn off Apache and other servers you might be running.

This could be a starting point for you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: It seems to use WEBrick as a default server I have heard this isn't powerful for production? also I have big php projects hosted there (i develop apps for codecanyon) and i don't want to get rid of php can I run them both?

Comment: install thin or puma as your server. if you want to run both php and ruby you will need to serve it from a different domain I guess.